# Run functions for LED flashing and Buzzer sound simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading, gpio

I'm working on a little Raspberry Pi security project that has LEDs, a piezoelectric buzzer, a 9 digit keypad, and an LCD screen (Full Source Here: https://github.com/kevbo423/RPHSP/blob/master/Keypad.py).

In short, when a user enters an incorrect password with the keypad, I want the LEDs to flash and the buzzer to go off at the same time. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that happen. I have the functions for the LEDs and the Buzzer created and individually working, but can't get them to go off simultaneously.

```
# Function for error LED feedback
def errorLED():
    for i in range(3):
        GPIO.output(6,1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(6,0)
        GPIO.output(12,1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(12,0)
```

```
# Function for Buzzer Alarm Output
def buzzerAlarm():
    for i in range(3):
        GPIO.output(21,1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(21,0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

I looked into using the Threading module, but ran into issues when I tried to execute the thread for the Buzzer beeping multiple times. Below is the test code I created to try and run the Buzzer thread multiple times...

```
# Buzzer Test
buzzerSound = threading.Thread(target=buzzerAlarm())
buzzerSound.start()
time.sleep(3)
buzzerSound.start()
time.sleep(3)
buzzerSound.start()
time.sleep(3)
```

...and the error message I received.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Keypad.py", line 277, in <module>
    buzzerSound.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 730, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

Am I on the right track with the threading module? If so, should I be killing the Buzzer thread inside of the `BuzzerAlarm()` function or should I not be using `.start()` to run the function? Or do I need to be doing something else entirely? If threading isn't the best way to go, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start):

> `start()`
>
> It must be called at most once per thread object.

Therefore you should create a new `Thread` object if you want to start it again. For example:

```
buzzer_thread = threading.Thread(target=buzzerAlarm())
led_thread = threading.Thread(target=errorLED())
led_thread.start()
buzzer_thread.start()
time.sleep(3)

# Second time:
buzzer_thread = threading.Thread(target=buzzerAlarm())
led_thread = threading.Thread(target=errorLED())
led_thread.start()
buzzer_thread.start()
```

You may consider refactoring this into a function:

```
def buzzer_and_led():
    buzzer_thread = threading.Thread(target=buzzerAlarm())
    led_thread = threading.Thread(target=errorLED())
    led_thread.start()
    buzzer_thread.start()
    # Wait until both the buzzer and the LED stop
    while led_thread.is_alive() or buzzer_thread.is_alive():
       pass
```

Comment: Ah ha! That's what I was misunderstanding. Thank you! Does the threading object get destroyed once the thread ends? Hence the ability to reuse the object name "buzzer_thread" and "led_thread"?

Comment: @KevinTate No, it will simply stop (i.e. `is_alive()` will return `False`) but the object will still be in memory. Variable names are just names, you don't need for an object to be destroyed to reuse a name. The reference counter will garbage collect the orphan object in memory if there are no references pointing to it, so you don't need to care about the (now inactive) `Thread` object.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation @Selcuk!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **not** a multi-threading answer, this answer should still work either way.

Okay, quick answer. What you could do is combine the two functions

```
# Function for error LED feedback
def errorLED():
    for i in range(3):
        GPIO.output(6,1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(6,0)
        GPIO.output(12,1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(12,0)
# Function for Buzzer Alarm Output
def buzzerAlarm():
    for i in range(3):
        GPIO.output(21,1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(21,0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

This would become

```
#Combined function
def combined():
    for i in range(3):
        GPIO.output(6,1) #Error LED
        GPIO.output(21,1) #Alarm Buzzer
        time.sleep(0.25) #Notice times changed by 0.05 so it can do the combination easyer
        GPIO.output(6,0)
        GPIO.output(12,1)
        time.sleep(0.25)
        GPIO.output(12,0)
        #Repeats Code 
        GPIO.output(6,1)
        GPIO.output(21,0) #Only difference is turning off the buzzer/alarm
        time.sleep(0.25) 
        GPIO.output(6,0)
        GPIO.output(12,1)
        time.sleep(0.25)
        GPIO.output(12,0)
```

Tell me if this works, I have not used my Raspberry PI in a while

Comment: Not sure if this would be acceptable. Apart from different timings, the error LED will flash 6 times instead of 3 times as in OPs code.